# LAME library in Audacity

Tags: audacity, lame

Does anybody know which version of LAME library works with Audacity program?

I would like to export sound into MP3. I downloaded latest Audacity (29.6.2012) and latest LAME lib (28.2.2012), but Audacity says `This version is not compatible with Audacity - please download the latest version of LAME library.`

Answer (score 2):

The Audacity manual has up to date links for LAME and FFmpeg known to work with the current version of Audacity: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/faq_installation_and_plug_ins.html#lame

Comment: You really should quote and cite the relevant information from your link.  So if and when that manual is no longer available your answer is helpful to the community.

Comment: The versions of LAME and FFmpeg can be updated at any time. The documentation in the Audacity manual is kept up to date, but there is no guarantee that this thread on superuser will be.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version of LAME from the site below, you are using Audacity 2.0.1 btw.

> http://lame1.buanzo.com.ar/

Comment: Wow, 3.99.3 works! thank you :) I was testing LAME 3.99.5, but it didn't work.
By the way, there is a bug that LAME adds 0.05s of silence to the beginning of each MP3 file. But it is a feature - http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt

Comment: @IvanKuckir Welcome to Super User, you can accept an answer by clicking the tick mark, this allows future users to know that this is the solution

Comment: Thank you :) but - Vote Up requires 15 reputation :(